# CSS Line Height and Padding

Tags: formatting, word-wrap, css

I have a box that is 300px wide and 30px high.  I have text that wraps and goes onto the next line.  The first line of text is vertically aligned close to the center.  But the broken second line is still shown slightly in the box.

How do I either keep the line from being broken (on 1 line), or use line-height = 30px but have the text vertically aligned in the center?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work:

`white-space: nowrap;`